# Arduino to post to web api

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I am an absolute beginner when it comes to c++. Now I need to write some code to read values from my DHT11 sensor and send them to a server via http get. All I could do was look at arduino example code and throw stuff together, so I'm sure it is not pretty. But I was hoping somebody could help a noob out by telling me why it is not working.

This is the code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "DHT.h";
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// Pin für DHT11 Sensor festlegen
#define DHTPIN 4

// Typ definieren
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

const char* ssid     = "mySSID";
const char* password = "myWiFiPW";

const char* host = "IP";
const char* myDev     = "deviceNAME";
const char* myUsr     = "me";
const char* myPwd     = "myPW";

// folgende Variabeln __nicht__ ändern
char urlHum[80];
char urlTem[80];
char str_temp[8];
char str_hum[8];

// Namen des Sensors definieren
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10); 
  }



void loop() {
  int value = 0;
  dht.begin();
  delay(5000);
  ++value;

  // Luftfeuchtigkeit auslesen und als "Luftfeuchte" speichern
  float feuchte = dht.readHumidity();
  dtostrf(feuchte, 2, 4, str_hum);

  // Temperatur auslesen und als "Tempe" speichern
  float tempe = dht.readTemperature();
  dtostrf(feuchte, 2, 4, str_temp);


  // Verbindung mit WiFi herstellen
  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 80;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  // We now create a URI for the request
  sprintf(urlHum,"http://%s:%s@%s/api/device/%s/changeHumidityTo=humidity=%s", myUsr, myPwd, host, myDev, str_hum);
  sprintf(urlTem,"http://%s:%s@%s/api/device/%s/changeTemperatureTo=temperatue=%s", myUsr, myPwd, host, myDev, str_temp);


  //Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  //Serial.println(urlHum);

  // This will send the request to the server
  client.print(String("GET ") + urlHum + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
          // "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
           "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  client.print(String("GET ") + urlTem + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
          // "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
           "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");  
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  }



  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection");
}
```

This should just add the read values to two URLs and then send those to my server as HTTP GET. However, it does not. It only creates an error log way too long to paste in here. Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Maybe you could add the error output. It increases chance of getting a useful answer by a lot

Comment: You can't send two HTTP requests in a single connection. You are using HTTP authentication wrong. You only need the path part of the URL not the schema, username, password, host or port. And HTTP/1.1 requires the Host header.